# CSS - Slow Hover effect

Tags: html, css

I am creating a CSS dynamic menu and would like to delay the on hover action. The reaction of the menu to when hovering over it's links is to provide a sub menu(drop down).

I would like to slow down the drop down process so that the sub menu would not appear instantly, but would take 1 second to drop down. Help is greatly appreciated.

Code is below:

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
#navMenu{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#navMenu ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}
#navMenu li{
    margin-right:2px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background:#CCC;
}
#navMenu ul li a{
    text-align:center;
    font-family:sans-serif, cursive;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:30px;
    width:150px;
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    border:10px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  transition: background-color 0.1s;
}
#navMenu ul ul{
        position:absolute;
        visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  transition: background-color 0.1s;
}

#navMenu ul li:hover ul{
    visibility:visible; 
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  transition: background-color 0.1s;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper"><!--beginning of wrapper div-->
<div id="navMenu"><!--Beginning of Nav Menu-->
    <ul><!--Beginning of main UL-->
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
            <ul><!--Begining of Internal UL-->
                <li><a href="#">Link item </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link item </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link item </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link item </a></li>
            </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul><!--End of Main UL --></div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Regards,

Joseph

Comment: 1s is actually a REALLY long time and, arguably, would be poor UX for a hover.

Comment: Perhaps I have not made myself clear enough. I do not want the sub menu to appear after 1 second with the mouse standing over the button. 

I want it to take 1 second to drop the menu down.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your post. Simply declaring the time as 1s in the transition is the answer though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use css transition-delay property as follows:

```
transition-delay: 1s; /* delays for 1 second */
-webkit-transition-delay: 1s; /* for Safari & Chrome */
```

Find more info here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp

Answer (score 30):

You can add an `ease` in the transition.

```
transition: all .4s ease;
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for. Gradually, slowly changing the component.
Thank you!

Comment: Perfect . Just the solution I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: A solid one. I will definitely prefer your solution than the accepted one over there.

Comment: Nice. I want to **remove** this from every website I maintain. I hate this effect. Computers are slow enough as it is; don't need to fake them being even slower. Now I know what to search for.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `transition-delay` property for this.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K4XJh/)

**Update**

Since you want the animation to complete in one second, you simply need to state that as your duration.  For example:  `transition: background-color 1s linear;`

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K4XJh/1/)

Comment: Perhaps I have not made myself clear enough. I do not want the sub menu to appear after 1 second with the mouse standing over the button. 

I want it to take 1 second to drop the menu down.

Comment: transition: background-color 1s linear; is best answer for my search...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sub menu to take 1 second to drop down, rather than it delaying for 1 second before it drops down, one option for complete control over acceleration and movement (if you want to get fancy) is to use [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) and [@keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

Here is a [cool demo](http://www.impressivewebs.com/demo-files/css3-animated-scene/) showing off the level of control you have with CSS animations.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `visibility:hidden`, this cannot be transitioned as you might think...it only has an on and off state.

What you can do is combine it with `opacity` and use transition delays to offset the appearance until the opacity has kicked in.

Here. [**http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337**](http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337)

Answer (score 0):

**Check this working DEMO**

```css
.transition{
    transition: all .4s;
    -moz-transition: all .4s;
    -webkit-transition:all .4s;
    -o-transition: all .4s;
    
    margin-top:20px;
    border:1px solid gray;   
    width:80px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:50px;
    position:relative; 
    cursor:pointer;
}

.hover_top{ 
    top:0;
}
.hover_top:hover{
    top:-10px;
}

.hover_left{    
    left:0;
}
.hover_left:hover{
    left:-10px;
}

.hover_right{   
    right:0;
}
.hover_right:hover{
    right:-10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="hover_top transition"> Hover Top </div>
 <div class="hover_left transition"> Hover Left </div>
 <div class="hover_right transition"> Hover Right </div>
```